# Getting an error in output when passing dynamic variable in ElFileBody in Gatling 3.0.3

Tags: gatling

I am using Gatling 3.0.3 and Java home is set to Jdk9. I am getting an error when running my script using 'ElFileBody' and I am passing a dynamic variable Session_ID in the ElFileBody .txt file.  Below is my code

```
.exec(http("TEAMXPRESS_INIT")
   .post("/WEBXPAPIT/api/Common/wxRequestHandlerJSON")     
   .headers(headers_7)
.body(ElFileBody("bodies/resources/TeamXPLoginUnSchShift_0021_request.txt")).sJson                                                      

  .check( jsonPath( "$" ).saveAs( "TEAMXP_INIT_RESPONSE_DATA" ) )
  .check(status.in(200))
  .check(jsonPath("$.pcResult").is("OK")))
```

bodies/resources/TeamXPLoginUnSchShift_0021_request.txt file is

```
{"pcwxSessionID":"${Session_ID)","pcServiceName":"TeamXpressInit","pcContextString":"{\"ttContext\":[{\"contextName\":\"pcToken\",\"contextValue\":null,\"contextGroup\":\"PARAM\",\"contextOperator\":\"\",\"contextType\":\"\"},{\"contextName\":\"pcPlatform\",\"contextValue\":null,\"contextGroup\":\"PARAM\",\"contextOperator\":\"\",\"contextType\":\"\"}]}","piClientVersion":"20190414001","pcIODataSetString":""}
```

Error I am getting is

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.gatling.core.session.el.ElParserException: Failed to parse {"pcwxSessionID":"${Session_ID)","pcServiceName":"TeamXpressInit","pcContextString":"{\"ttContext\":[{\"contextName\":\"pcToken\",\"contextValue\":null,\"contextGroup\":\"PARAM\",\"contextOperator\":\"\",\"contextType\":\"\"},{\"contextName\":\"pcPlatform\",\"contextValue\":null,\"contextGroup\":\"PARAM\",\"contextOperator\":\"\",\"contextType\":\"\"}]}","piClientVersion":"20190414001","pcIODataSetString":""} with error ''}' expected but ')' found'
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalLoadingCache.lambda$new$0(BoundedLocalCache.java:3373)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2039)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1922)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2037)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2020)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:112)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalLoadingCache.java:67)
    at io.gatling.core.body.ElFileBodies.asBytesSeq(ElFileBodies.scala:71)
    at io.gatling.core.body.ElFileBody$.apply(Body.scala:34)
    at teamXPLogin.TeamXPLoginUnSchShift.<init>(TeamXPLoginUnSchShift.scala:86)
```

What wrong am I doing here. If I pass the post request body manually using StringBody method then it works fine. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the silly mistake I have done. Instead of passing dynamic variable ${Session_ID} like this, I have passed ${Session_ID).